# Where do Sony Android phones store deleted pictures?

Tags: data-recovery, mobile-data, sony-xperia, files

I was thinking to copy the specific file to my PC and scan it with third party application. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, Android has no "recycle bin" concept.

Comment: If you use `Google Photos` it should be saved in `trash`

Comment: You might wish to take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info) – and [my list of de-deletion apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872). As @DeathMaskSalesman correctly pointed out, Android has no native "Recycle Bin". My app list has some apps adding that (or trying to recover even if you had none) – and the linked tag-wiki additionally has some alternative hints of how to recover via your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Like Death Mask Salesman said, there is not an Android recycle bin. However, there are apps you can download on your PC to scan your phone and potentially recover a deleted photo. Here are a few (note: I haven't tried any of these and am not affiliated with any of them):

https://airmore.com/recover-deleted-android-photos.html

https://www.easeus.com/android-data-recovery/how-to-recover-deleted-photos-from-android-phone.html

or look up fonepaw

Good luck!

Comment: Um. Looks like some community members consider this spam (due to the websites linked, which make it look promotional). Maybe rather link to the apps on Playstore instead – and include a few details on your choice? Other pointers you could integrate: our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info) and [my list of de-deletion apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872), which also includes some "recycle bins"?

Comment: Yeah, Airmore are frequent spammers of this site, so I wouldn't recommend their software at all, especially when it works by rooting your phone, and you don't know what else they might install on there.